# Why can't I add any value to the array in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algolia, react-instantsearch

I have a lot of hits, which I want to add to an array once a hit is pressed. However, as far as I observed, the array looked like it got the name of the hit, which is the value. The value was gone in like half second.

I have tried the methods like building constructor, and doing things like

```
onClick={e => this.handleSelect(e)}
value={hit.name}
onClick={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}
value={hit.name}
onClick={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}
defaultValue={hit.name}
```

and so on

```
export default class Tagsearch extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dropDownOpen:false,
      text:"",
      tags:[]
    };

    this.handleRemoveItem = this.handleRemoveItem.bind(this);
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
    this.handleTextChange = this.handleTextChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleSelect = (e) => {
    this.setState(
      { tags:[...this.state.tags, e.target.value] 
    });
  }


  render() {

    const HitComponent = ({ hit }) => {
      return (
        <div className="infos">
          <button 
            className="d-inline-flex p-2" 
            onClick={e => this.handleSelect(e)}
            value={hit.name}
          >
            <Highlight attribute="name" hit={hit} />
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }

    const MyHits = connectHits(({ hits }) => {
      const hs = hits.map(hit => <HitComponent key={hit.objectID} hit={hit}/>);
      return <div id="hits">{hs}</div>;
    })

    return (
      <InstantSearch
        appId="JZR96HCCHL"
        apiKey="b6fb26478563473aa77c0930824eb913"
        indexName="tags"
      >

        <CustomSearchBox />
        {result}

      </InstantSearch>
    )
  }
}
```

Basically, what I want is to pass the name of the hit component to handleSelect method once the corresponding button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the hit.name value into the arrow function.

Full working code example (simple paste into codesandbox.io):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const HitComponent = ({ hit, handleSelect }) => {
    return <button onClick={() => handleSelect(hit)}>{hit.name}</button>;
};

class Tagsearch extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            tags: []
        };
    }

    handleSelect = value => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return { tags: [...prevState.tags, value] };
        });
    };

    render() {
        const hitList = this.props.hitList;

        return hitList.map(hit => (
            <HitComponent key={hit.id} hit={hit} handleSelect={this.handleSelect} />
        ));
    }
}

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Tagsearch
                hitList={[
                    { id: 1, name: "First" },
                    { id: 2, name: "Second" },
                    { id: 3, name: "Third" }
                ]}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

additionally:

- note the use of prevState! This is a best practice when modifying state. You can google as to why!
- you should define the HitComponent component outside of the render method. it doesn't need to be redefined each time the component is rendered!

Comment: As you suggested, I revised my code, but the name still doesn't go into the array.